# Proper way to connect gutters

Tags: water, leak, gutters, downspout

[image]

The picture above is where a gutter over the porch connects to a gutter over the garage for my home. As you can see, two gutters are connected using a downspout at an angle leaving a section of the roof outside of any gutters (water not collected).

As a result, water from that segment runs over the downspout and is dripping down where the downspout is connected to the below gutter. This is right above the porch entry. As such, this is not a huge problem in the summer, but in the spring the water from above can get frozen right by the house entry creating as hazard. How can I improve this to properly collect all water?

Comment: Gutters are not typically installed on the rake.

Comment: Usually you would have the water draining at the bottom from the top gutter into a downspout.  Add a 45 elbow to your downspout to the next gutter.

Comment: This isn't really a top gutter/bottom gutter situation, so a downspout isn't appropriate in any orientation.  The correct way would be to miter in another piece of open gutter where you currently have a piece of downspout, so you basically have a trough running along the entire length of fascia board.  But you have what you have, and @crip659's solution is as good as any.  You could probably also simply add a short section of straight downspout around the end, so long as the end ends up around the midline of the bottom gutter.

Comment: @Huesmann Isn't your idea here the way to solve the OP's problem - "The correct way would be to miter in another piece of open gutter where you currently have a piece of downspout, so you basically have a trough running along the entire length of fascia board. " They are complaining about water running over the edge of the roof shingles and eventually down onto the ground because of no collection trough in that middle section.

Comment: @Armand That's correct.